# I need to find the top 5 numbers in a 2D array of random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, random

I am pretty new to java and am just learning 2D arrays. I need to get the top 5 numbers and have tried everything I could think of. I was able to get the highest number using an If statement but am not able to get past that. I figured that I would try and get the second number and then move on to the rest. My friend said he got it done using for loops but I also could not get that to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is the code that I used:

```
package secondAssignment;

import java.util.Random;

public class BiggestNumbersRectangular {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int[][] arrSize = new int [4][5];
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j< arrSize.length; j++) {
                arrSize[i][j] = rand.nextInt(89) + 10;
                
                System.out.print(arrSize[i][j] + " ");
            }
                
            System.out.println();
            
        }
        
        int max = arrSize [0][0];
        int largeNumTwo = arrSize [0][0];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrSize.length; j++) {
        if (max < arrSize[i][j]) {
            max = arrSize [i][j];

        if (largeNumTwo < max) {
            arrSize [i][j] = largeNumTwo;
            
        }
        }
        }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Highest Number: " + max);
        System.out.println("Second Highest Number:" + largeNumTwo);
  
 }
}
```

The output that I get is this:

```
45 10 44 70 
36 87 35 38 
68 14 30 79 
34 69 50 92 
Highest Number: 92
Second Highest Number:45
```

The code that I used for the second number is outputting only the first randomly generated number.
I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Before you try to manipulate the data in your 2D array, consider whether you are actually generating your array correctly. The line `int[][] arrSize = new int [4][5];` suggests you want to create a "4 by 5" array. Is that what your code actually creates? If not, why not?

Comment: Personally, I hate the `i` and `j` variable names that seem to get perpetuated for some reason. Those are stupid variable names; the code and concept of a 2D array would be way easier to understand if you change `i` to `row`, and `j` to `col`!

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use a `List`, then I'd do it this way.

There's nothing terribly fancy in here:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main { 
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[][] arrSize = new int [4][5];
        
    for (int row = 0; row < arrSize.length; row++) {
      for (int col=0; col < arrSize[row].length; col++) {
        arrSize[row][col] = rand.nextInt(89) + 10;        
      }       
    } 

    displayArray(arrSize);

    List<Integer> top5 = new ArrayList();
    for (int row = 0; row < arrSize.length; row++) {
      for (int col=0; col < arrSize[row].length; col++) {        
        int current = arrSize[row][col];
        
        // see if current is larger than anything in top5
        boolean added = false;
        for(int i=0; i<top5.size() && !added; i++) {
          if (current >= top5.get(i)) {
            // insert new top 5 number in correct spot
            top5.add(i, current);
            added = true;
          }
        }
        if (!added && top5.size() < 5) {
          top5.add(current); // add it to the end
        }
        else if (added && top5.size() > 5) {
          top5.remove(top5.size() - 1); // remove 6th largest
        }
      }       
    }

    // display the top 5 numbers from the 2D array    
    for(int i=0; i<top5.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("#" + (i+1) + ": " + top5.get(i));
    }
  }

  public static void displayArray(int[][] numbers) {
    for(int[] row : numbers) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));  
    }
  }
  
}
```

Sample run:

```
[38, 63, 19, 17, 11]
[49, 42, 98, 71, 32]
[54, 74, 89, 44, 56]
[56, 91, 52, 72, 49]
#1: 98
#2: 91
#3: 89
#4: 74
#5: 72
```

This is basically the same approach that Javohir Xoldorov took, but the code is a little easier to understand because we can easily add, insert, and delete elements from a List without having to manually shift everything like you would in an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can see this solution.
Approach:
you can declare five variable but then You will use most if so  we can:

1. Declare static array size = 5
2. Fill array which possible min val INT_MIN
3. We get one element given matrix and compare five element If which element < firstArray[i] then it changed and before matrix element one step move right side

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int[][] arr = new int[4][5];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = rand.nextInt(89) + 10;

                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();

        }

        int[] max_element = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < max_element.length; i++) {
            max_element[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < max_element.length; k++) {
                    if (max_element[k] < arr[i][j]) {
                        int before = max_element[k], current;
                        for (int z = k + 1; z < max_element.length; z++) {
                            current = max_element[z];
                            max_element[z] = before;
                            before = current;
                        }
                        max_element[k] = arr[i][j];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < max_element.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + " Highest Number: " + max_element[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: wirepirate Is this code correct or incorrect ?

Comment: At least fix the random number generation part so that it actually fills the entire array. That's a pretty big bug in the original code. Change `for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {` to `for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {`.

Comment: 1. The code works up until printing out the 5 numbers, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @JavohirXoldorov what is a "dynamic array" ?

Comment: @cyberbrain Sorry I make a mistake , I will say static (updated) Thanks notify.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2: After testing, I changed my algorithm now finally to work really correctly if the highest value of all is contained within the first five entries. And I produced code:

```java
package examples.stackoverflow.q75461466;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Q75461466 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] myArray = initRandomArray(4, 5, 79, 10);

// for testing it's better to work with a fixed dataset
//    int[][] myArray = {{94, 61, 17, 27, 67}, {68, 74, 46, 61, 98}, {42, 79, 95, 77, 39}, {41, 42, 97, 50, 76}};
    System.out.print("Original data: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));

    List<Integer> topFive = new ArrayList<>();

    Integer min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int[] row : myArray) {
      for (int value : row) {
        if ((value > min) || topFive.size() < 5) {
          topFive.add(value);
          if (topFive.size() > 5) {
            topFive.remove(min);
          }
          min = topFive.stream().min(Integer::compareTo).orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.print("The 5 highest numbers are: ");
    System.out.println(topFive);
  }

  private static int[][] initRandomArray(int height, int width, int upper, int lower) {
    int[][] randomArray = new int[height][width];
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int row = 0; row < randomArray.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < randomArray[row].length; col++) {
        randomArray[row][col] = rand.nextInt(upper + lower) + lower;
      }
    }
    return randomArray;
  }
}
```

First the array is initialized and filled with data in the method `initRandomArray`. Please note that for testing it is better if you work with a fixed array, it will get you reproducible results where you also can simulate "problematic" cases.

Then the list `topFive` is used - a name a bit misleading, because it does not contain five elements all the time.

I loop over all the entries in the arrays with two nested loops (the code is written to be independent of the actual array dimensions, otherwise further optimizations could have been done).
Array indexes are not necessary, the for-each variant is sufficient, as I only need each value once.

I make sure that the first five entries are always put into the `topFive` list, and I always track the minimum value inside that list (in `min`). For this I use a bit "stream magic", the `orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` in the end is needed since the `min` method returns an `Optional` in the case the list is empty. Should never happen in this algorithm, but the `Optional` has to be handled properly.

After five values are in the list, it is relevant if the next input value is bigger than the smallest value already in the list - if so, then the input value is added to the list, and the current minimum value is removed.
The new minimum value has to be calculated, as the value just inserted is not necessarily the new minimum.

After all values of the arrays have been processed, the list contains five values at maximum, so it can be directly output as the result.

The resulting list will not be sorted, but will contain the values in the order of their first occurrence.

In the case that the first five input values contain a value more than once, it is possible that the output list contains the same value also more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing this using Java's `PriorityQueue` class. While it might be overkill for 5 items, it's quite straightforward to use and will perform extremely well for larger target sets.

The default constructor gives a min priority queue, which is exactly what we want. Add the first `desiredQty` items to the priority queue. The minimum of those will be at the front of the queue, and can be inspected using `peek()`. For all subsequent values in the array, compare them to the current minimum value. If the new value is larger than the current minimum, toss the min and add the current value. When you get to the end of the array the priority queue will contain the `desiredQty` largest values, so you can just iterate through and print them (or do whatever else suits your fancy).

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class Top5 { 
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

    int[][] arr = new int [4][5];
    int desiredQty = 5;
        
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
      for (int col=0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
        arr[row][col] = rand.nextInt(89) + 10; 
        if (pq.size() < desiredQty) {
          // If we don't yet have desiredQty items, just add the latest one to pq.
          pq.add(arr[row][col]);
        } else {
          // If pq has the desiredQty and the latest value is bigger than
          // the current min, remove the min and add the latest value.
          if (arr[row][col] > pq.peek()) {
            pq.poll();
            pq.add(arr[row][col]);
          }
        }
      }       
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[row]));
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + desiredQty + " largest values are:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pq.toArray()));
  } 
}
```

Sample output:

```text
[55, 82, 92, 93, 79]
[84, 26, 78, 87, 23]
[49, 67, 76, 37, 18]
[12, 39, 54, 38, 68]

5 largest values are:
[82, 84, 92, 93, 87]
```