# How to get the top 5 numbers from a 2D array of random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, random

I am pretty new to java and am just learning 2D arrays. I am trying to get the top 5 numbers to display from a random list. I think this could work but am not sure why I am getting an error. One other thing is that I cannot use the sort function.

Code here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 //Random Number stuff
        Random rand = new Random();
        
        int[] large = new int [5];
        
        int max = 0, index;

        int[][] arrSize = new int [4][5];
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j< arrSize[i].length; j++) {
                arrSize[i][j] = rand.nextInt(89) + 10;
                
                System.out.print(arrSize[i][j] + " ");
            }
                
            System.out.println();
            
        }
        // Top 5
        for (int p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
        max = arrSize [0][0];
        index = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrSize[i].length; j++) {
                
                if (max < arrSize[i][j]) {
                    
                    max = arrSize[i][j];
                    index = i;
                    
                }
        }
        }
        
        
        large[p] = max;
        arrSize[index] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  //Error here
        
            System.out.println("Highest Number: " + large[p]);
    }
 
}
}
```

Error text:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]

    at secondAssignment.BiggestNumbersRectangular.main(BiggestNumbersRectangular.java:47)
```

I am not sure why I am getting an error, any help would appreciated. If anyone else has any answers for how I could get the top 5 in a different way that would also be appreciated.

Comment: arrSize is 2d array that mean it's array of arrays so`arrSize[index]` will return the array on index `index` so `arrSize[index] = Integer.MIN_VALUE` it complain here that you tried to put int value inside that array which is array of int not an int thi the error you get

Comment: Don't you already have helpful or usable answers in your earlier question? [I need to find the top 5 numbers in a 2D array of random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75461466/12567365) Instead of repeating much of the same code, you could write a [mre] here - just enough code to recreate this new (very specific) problem - but no extra irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in other parts of the code, to access values in 2D array arrSize, you need 2 indexes in your case (and usually) `i` and `j`.

You need to save both `i` and `j` after you find the highest number.

```
if (max < arrSize[i][j]) {
   max = arrSize[i][j];
   indexI = i;
   indexJ = j;
}
```

and then

```
arrSize[indexI][indexJ] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

---

As to why you got the error, `arrSize[i]` gets you a 1D array. It's still an array and you cannot set an array to an integer (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`). in Java represented as `int[]` in the error message.

---

The algorithm could be improved, instead of using a single integer `max` for saving the highest value, you could use a `maxArr` of the same size as the number of highest numbers you want (in your case 5) and check against all of the numbers in `maxArr` using a for in place of

```
if (max < arrSize[i][j]) {
   max = arrSize[i][j];
   index = i;
}
```

That would mean you could remove the index (or indexI and indexJ) and topmost `for` cycle (`for (int p = 0; p < 5; p++)`). But that's another topic, and one you should learn yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You declare your `arrSize` here

```java
int[][] arrSize = new int [4][5];
```

and try to set it's value here

```java
arrSize[index] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

The Object at `arrSize[index]` is an array.

Remember that a 2D array basically looks like this:

```
arrSize
  - arrSize[0]
    - arrSize[0][0]
    - arrSize[0][1]
  - arrSize[1]
    - arrSize[1][0]
    - arrSize[1][1]
  - arrSize[2]
    - arrSize[2][0]
    - arrSize[2][1]
  - arrSize[3]
    - arrSize[3][0]
    - arrSize[3][1]
```

Because index is a single int, you are assentially calling arrSize[0], which contains `arrSize[0][0]` and `arrSize[0][1]`.

The [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) is not an array of integers.  It is an `int`.  You cannot assign `int` to `int[]`.